# Read whole message from serial port

Tags: java, serial-port

I have box which sends me every 5s control message ***#2214*** over Serial Port, but when something happen this box sends me expected message eg. ***$22021CB47E06B9B97BA56600*** I need to work with this "dolar message", but I need whole message. When I ran code from java the output from box looks like

> AVAILABLE 6
>
> #2214
>
> AVAILABLE 1
>
> AVAILABLE 7
>
> #2214
>
> AVAILABLE 1
>
> $
>
> AVAILABLE 14
>
> 22021CB47E06B9
>
> AVAILABLE 12
>
> B97BA56600
>
> AVAILABLE 4
>
> #221
>
> AVAILABLE 3
>
> 4

It is some way how to wait on all bytes if you don't know the size of message?
There is piece of my code. I was tried a lots of ways. Thanks for help.

```
public static class SerialReader implements Runnable {

    InputStream in;
    SerialPort comPort;

    public SerialReader(InputStream in, SerialPort comPort) {
        this.in = in;
        this.comPort = comPort;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        comPort.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {

            @Override
            public int getListeningEvents() {
                return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE;
            }

            @Override
            public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
                try {
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

                    if (event.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE) {
                        return;
                    }

                    int i = 0; 
                    while ((i = in.available()) > 0) {
                         byte[] readBuffer = new byte[i];
                        in.read(readBuffer);
                        System.out.println("AVAILIBLE "+i);
                        System.out.println(new String(readBuffer));
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SerialPortReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `in`? I presume it's some kind of `InputStream`? It also looks like there may be `\r\l` characters at the end of each message? Would it work to wrap the `InputStream` in a `BufferedReader`, via `InputStreamReader`, and call `readLine()` to get each complete message?

Comment: Yeah, in is InputStream, sorry fot that. I edited the code. I tried BufferedReader, but it throws some type of Exception. I will paste the Exception here, when I will come in front of my laptop.

Comment: You made my day. @SirRaffleBuffle I looked on the exception better. There was a timeout error so I added the read timeout an everything is working fine. Thanks

Comment: That's great. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The result is in using `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(InputStream)` instead of classic InputStream, but this solution throws Timeout Exceptions, because timeout was set by default to `0`. So I added `READ_TIMEOUT` and everything is work.

```
public void connect(String portName) throws Exception {
    SerialPort serialPort = availiblePorts().get(portName);
    if (serialPort.isOpen()) {
        System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
    } else {
        serialPort.openPort(2000);
        serialPort.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0);
        serialPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING, 500, 0);

        InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();

        (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
    }
}
```

[This is usage example from JSerialComm](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/wiki/Blocking-and-Semiblocking-Reading-Usage-Example)